# Modifying string with a condition

Tags: r

I want to change specific names within a list, using a condition

Here is the list of string items

```
varnames <- c("var1_L1","var2_L1","var3_L1",  "var4_L1",  "Coefs_L1", "Pval_L1")
```

I would like to remove everything to the right of "_" but only for items that have "var" in the text

This will remove everything for all items

```
sub("_.*","", varnames)
```

I've tried to use an if condition with this but couldn't get it to work.

If it helps, this would be what the end result looks like

```
varnames_result <- c("var1","var2","var3", "var4",  "Coefs_L1", "Pval_L1")
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Can `var` ever come after `_`?

Comment: not for the names I have, I think the condition should be the same if "var1_L1" and "variable_L1" as both have "var".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do:

```
 sub("(var.*?)_.*", "\\1", varnames)
[1] "var1"     "var2"     "var3"     "var4"     "Coefs_L1" "Pval_L1"
```

If there is only one `_` then `(var.*)_.*` is sufficient

Comment: this works pretty well for the data I have, i will keep in mind that it will take it from the first "_" after the "var", but luckily I don't have that with my data. thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use posiitve lookbehind regex to remove everything that follows `'var'` + number.

```
sub('(?<=var\\d).*', '', varnames, perl = TRUE)
#[1] "var1"     "var2"     "var3"     "var4"     "Coefs_L1" "Pval_L1"
```